# Is it possible to execute Ex Commands (colon commands) in VimScript (vimrc/init.vim)?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin

**First off, just an FYI: I am not that experienced with writing VimScript**

I have a [plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/rainbow_parentheses.vim) that I want to have enabled using its custom Ex command (`:RainbowParentheses`). Putting that inside my init.vim:

```
:RainbowParentheses
```

I found that it does not work and Vim (Neovim) throws an error saying the command is "Not an Editor command". I assume just throwing an Ex command into your `vimrc` or `init.vim` would not work. How would I be able to execute an Ex command in my `init.vim`? Would I be using a VimScript function to enable it if I had several other commands of a similar nature?

Comment: You can and such command. The problem is that the command is probably not yet defined when you call it. Could you try to put at the of your ``.vimrc`` file?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: Just to be clear, [every command in Vimscript is an Ex command](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#script).

Comment: The VimHelp page was very informative and provided more clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe @VivianDeSmedt's comment refers to `:help startup` (notice that the vimrc is executed *after* files like `plugin/*.vim` and others have loaded).

In general you cannot use a command until it has been defined. The standard Ex commands (lowercase letters) are all available at any time; for a user-defined command, place the invocation logically after the definition.

For a command defined in your vimrc, this means placing `:RainbowParentheses` after the `:command RainbowParentheses …` that defines it.

For a command defined by a plugin, a solution like the following usually works (since `VimEnter` is triggered at the end of `:help startup`):

```
augroup rainbow_parens
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * RainbowParentheses
augroup end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the explanation! I suggest maybe editing your answer to include links to the Vim help.txt so future users like me can quickly understand some of the things you are referencing.

Comment: If someone has the web links they are free to add them since anyone can [edit] @UnrealApex. The commands will work regardless of your internet connection or if you are on your phone or something. I don’t add the links because I don’t use them, but I’m happy to approve edits that add them.

Comment: If you want to you can, if no one edits in a couple of days I could just do the edits myself.